# tfs workitem field customization

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is there a way in team foundation server 2010 to make a work item field readonly based on a date value from another field?

E.g. if a deadline has passed, i need to make one of work item field's readonly. I'm trying to avoid client deployment for this feature and trying to run everything from server. Is it possible using work flows,custom fields?

Thanks

Comment: assumption: has to happen automatically without a need for a state change or any user action.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. A workaround achieve this is, by not using a specific date, but by using iterations. You can make a work item readonly when it is in a specific iteration. It is not exactly what you want, but it might work for you.

See the [rangers customization guide](http://vsartfsptguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/83765) how to achieve this.

Comment: Ewald, Thank you for your reply. I need to make only one field readonly not the entire work item template.